# Hand cursor not showing on links when Safari is inactive

Tags: cursor, mouse, safari

As the title says, every browser can show the hand cursor on links even when the window is inactive, but that's unfortunately not working on Safari v5.1.7 on Windows, last version installed today.

Does anyone know if that's a Safari bug? Has anyone an idea of how to solve or if it's possible to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that was a bug in safari.